# Pseudo inverse of matrix: SVD vs $A^{T}(A.A^{T})^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, svd

For a `C++` implementation I have to calculate `Moore Penrose Inverse` (AKA pseudo inverse) of non squared matrices. I was wondering what are advantages and disadvantages of doing this by the use of SVD or $A^{T}(A.A^{T})^{-1}$.

I'm concerned about 1. Computational complexity and 2. Behavior of each method near or at singularity.

Comment: Computational issues aside, since you want to compute the pseudoinverse of $A$, you should know that $A$ can be non-invertible. How can you possibly calculate the pseudoinverse as $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ then?

Comment: @user1551, thanks for the reply. Although in the question I've mentioned `at singularity`, but in practice the matrix does not lose rank. However, it can get very close to singularity. It is a 26x6 jacobian of many trigonometric functions on each element and it is very improbable that it isn't full rank. But again, it can get close to singularity.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @davips, Computationally, for what I did, left pseudo inverse was significantly faster than singular value decomposition. I used eigen library for matrix inversion and if I'm not so wrong, it uses LU decomposition to calculate inverse. The behavior near singularity, is a bit difficult to say. My matrices are consist of many random trigonometric functions and the chance of rank deficiency is really really small. I think you have to figure that our by yourself `;)`

Comment: Yep, left pseudo-inverse was faster to me too, but it was way more unstable, unfortunately. I used the solve() function from netlib/LAPACK (LU, maybe also).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you consider using $AA^T$ and "computation" in the same sentence, the answer will be "a bad idea". Consider the following:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1+x \\ 1+x & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad x = 10^{-8}.$$

Now, compute Moore-Penrose inverse via two methods, using Matlab:

```
>> format long;
>> x=1e-8;
>> A = [ 1 1+x; 1+x 1]

A =

   1.000000000000000   1.000000010000000
   1.000000010000000   1.000000000000000

>> A' * inv(A * A')
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 

ans =

   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf

>> pinvA = pinv(A)

pinvA =

   1.0e+07 *

  -5.000000110440711   5.000000160440710
   5.000000160440711  -5.000000110440711
```

As you can see, the first approach failed, because $AA^T$ lost enough of precision to render this matrix singular (even though it's not, because it is a product of two nonsingular matrices). The SVD method (which is behind Matlab's [`pinv`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html), doesn't have this problem.

In fact, SVD was invented specifically for the purpose of computing the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ without actually forming this numerically unstable product.

Of course, some precision is always lost in an extreme case like this one, as we can see by computing `A * pinv(A)`:

```
>> A * pinvA

ans =

   1.000000022351742  -0.000000014901161
                   0   1.000000007450581
```

Still, fairly close and certainly much better than the other approach.

Btw, $x = 10^{-7}$ will not cause an error, but the solution will be quite wrong:

```
>> x=1e-7;
>> A = [ 1 1+x; 1+x 1]

A =

   1.000000000000000   1.000000100000000
   1.000000100000000   1.000000000000000

>> pinvA = A' * inv(A * A')

pinvA =

   1.0e+06 *

  -4.895216742187500   4.895217242187500
   4.895217242187500  -4.895216742187500

>> A * pinvA

ans =

   0.989521724171937   0.010478325188160
   0.010478325188160   0.989521724171937
```